# When doing backpropagation, why do we multiply with the derivative of the activation function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation

I was reading about backpropagation, which in my case works like this:
[image]

I don't understand why when computing the error term, we are multiplying with the derivative of the activation function:
[image]

Why isn't this the formula instead?[image]

Comment: I like the Eric Wan diagrammatic version instead of the chain rule.  The derivative shows which parts contribute more or less, so splitting by it means you spread the error correction in a balanced way to the parts of the function where it does the best good.